# Rsync daemon error

Tags: linux, rhel, rsync

The daemon is being started as root.

```
[root@uhspaastream02 etc]# systemctl status -l UHS_FolderMonitor.service
    ● UHS_FolderMonitor.service - Starts the folder monitoring/logging script
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/UHS_FolderMonitor.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-02-02 15:42:49 EST; 41s ago
         Docs: man:systemd.service
      Process: 11491 ExecStart=/usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Main PID: 11491 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

    Feb 02 15:42:49 uhspaastream02.corp.uhsinc.biz systemd[1]: Starting Starts the folder monitoring/logging script...
    Feb 02 15:42:49 uhspaastream02.corp.uhsinc.biz rsyncd[11492]: rsync: failed to open log-file /var/log/rsync_activity.log: Permission denied (13)
    Feb 02 15:42:49 uhspaastream02.corp.uhsinc.biz rsyncd[11492]: Ignoring "log file" setting.
    Feb 02 15:42:49 uhspaastream02.corp.uhsinc.biz rsyncd[11492]: building file list
    Feb 02 15:42:49 uhspaastream02.corp.uhsinc.biz rsyncd[11492]: rsync: link_stat "/nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh" failed: Permission denied (13)
    Feb 02 15:42:49 uhspaastream02.corp.uhsinc.biz rsyncd[11492]: rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/NFSPRODW": Permission denied (13)
    Feb 02 15:42:49 uhspaastream02.corp.uhsinc.biz rsyncd[11492]: rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(565) [Receiver=3.0.9]
    Feb 02 15:42:49 uhspaastream02.corp.uhsinc.biz systemd[1]: Started Starts the folder monitoring/logging script.
```

Content of `/etc/rsyncd.conf`:

```
# /etc/rsyncd: configuration file for rsync daemon mode
# See rsyncd.conf man page for more options.
#pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
#log file = /var/log/samba/uhsrsync.log
uid = root
gid = root
use chroot = yes
max connections = 8
exclude = lost+found/
transfer logging = yes
timeout = 900
ignore nonreadable = yes
#log format = %o %h [%a] %m %b %f %l
dont compress   = *.gz *.tgz *.zip *.z *.Z *.rpm *.deb *.bz2
# [ftp]
#        path = /home/ftp
#        comment = ftp export area
```

Content of `/etc/systemd/system/UHS_FolderMonitor.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description= Starts the folder monitoring/logging script
Documentation= man:systemd.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh
```

Output of `ksh /usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh`:

```
 [root@uhspaastream02 NFSPRODW]$ ksh /usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh
 sending incremental file list
 rsync: link_stat "/nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/*.*" failed: No such file or 
 directory (2)

 sent 12 bytes  received 12 bytes  48.00 bytes/sec
 total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
 rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) 
 (code 23) at main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Content of `/var/log/rsync_activity.log`:

```
 [root@uhspaastream02 NFSPRODW]$ cat /var/log/rsync_activity.log
 2018/02/02 13:30:03 [3422] building file list
 2018/02/02 13:30:03 [3422] >f+++++++++ HHN Center_COWIN, JUSTIN 
 TYME_HHN8026539_HHN0005000372168_9.14.2017_p152w-258306975.pdf
 2018/02/02 13:30:03 [3422] sent 130.00K bytes  received 31 bytes  260.06K 
 bytes/sec
 2018/02/02 13:30:03 [3422] total size is 149.91K  speedup is 1.15
 2018/02/02 17:06:22 [13342] building file list
 2018/02/02 17:06:22 [13342] >f+++++++++ RTMS Project Update.docx
 2018/02/02 17:06:22 [13342] sent 11.17K bytes  received 31 bytes  22.40K 
 bytes/sec
 2018/02/02 17:06:22 [13342] total size is 14.00K  speedup is 1.25
 2018/02/12 09:33:22 [8120] building file list
 2018/02/12 09:33:22 [8120] rsync: link_stat "/nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/*.*" 
 failed: No such file or directory (2)
 2018/02/12 09:33:22 [8120] sent 12 bytes  received 12 bytes  48.00 
 bytes/sec
 2018/02/12 09:33:22 [8120] total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
 2018/02/12 09:33:22 [8120] rsync error: some files/attrs were not 
 transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]
 2018/02/12 09:37:02 [8206] building file list
 2018/02/12 09:37:02 [8206] rsync: link_stat "/nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/*.*" 
 failed: No such file or directory (2)
 2018/02/12 09:37:02 [8206] sent 12 bytes  received 12 bytes  48.00 
 bytes/sec
 2018/02/12 09:37:02 [8206] total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
 2018/02/12 09:37:02 [8206] rsync error: some files/attrs were not 
 transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]
 2018/02/12 09:37:35 [8218] building file list
 2018/02/12 09:37:35 [8218] rsync: link_stat "/nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/*.*" 
 failed: No such file or directory (2)
 2018/02/12 09:37:35 [8218] sent 12 bytes  received 12 bytes  48.00 
 bytes/sec
 2018/02/12 09:37:35 [8218] total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
 2018/02/12 09:37:35 [8218] rsync error: some files/attrs were not 
 transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Permission of `NFSPRODW`:

```
 [root@uhspaastream02 NFSPRODW]$ ls -ld /nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/
 drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root 4096 Feb 12 09:37 /nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/
```

Permission of `UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh`:

```
 [root@uhspaastream02 NFSPRODW]$ ls -ld /usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 724 Feb  2 16:31 /usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh
```

Code of `UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh`:

```
 [root@uhspaastream02 NFSPRODW]$ cat /usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh
 #!/bin/ksh
 # Description: Script that moves files to Windows NFS share via the systemd 
 UHS_FolderMonitor service file
 #              Service Filename is 
 /etc/systemd/system/UHS_FolderMonitor.service
 #              Service file above relies on the 
 /etc/systemd/system/UHS_FolderMonitor.path file
 #
 # Scriptname: /usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh
 #
 # Owner: 
 # Version 1.0
 # Last Updated:  01/24/18
 #
 #Change Log: Initial Create 01/24/18
 #
 # mv /nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/*.* /NFSPRODW
 /usr/bin/rsync --chmod=u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx --remove-source-files -r -zvh --
 log-file=/var/log/rsync_activity.log /nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/*.* /NFSPRODW
 echo `date` ' Rsync - File(s) moved to NFS Share' >>  
 /usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.log
```

I’m thinking this must be permissions causing this for the user running `rsyncd` daemon since the manually executed `rsync` command works just fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the 'user' from which daemon is being started (config sample). How do you start a service (show the '#systemctl start UHS_FolderMonitor.service')?

Comment: The deamon is being started as root. Below is the config. 
[root@uhspaastream02 ~]$ cat /etc/rsyncd.conf
# /etc/rsyncd: configuration file for rsync daemon mode
# See rsyncd.conf man page for more options.
#pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
#log file = /var/log/samba/uhsrsync.log
uid = root
gid = root
use chroot = yes
max connections = 8
exclude = lost+found/
transfer logging = yes
timeout = 900
ignore nonreadable = yes
#log format = %o %h [%a] %m %b %f %l
dont compress   = *.gz *.tgz *.zip *.z *.Z *.rpm *.deb *.bz2

Comment: OK. I haven't seen how you run service (all output from console is needed). I've seen that service start the following script: '/nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh'. Try to run this script from console from 'root' user and show all output.

Comment: Also, your console output and config samples are not readable. If you will have more time, please fix message formatting.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk Please check the original question I've updated with the config samples.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk I already have that file created. See output above. Thanks

Comment: Show permissions to this directory '/nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/'.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk I've added the permission of '/nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/' to the question also. Thanks

Comment: Please, place code of script '/usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh'. It seems, you need workaround for this case "rsync: link_stat "/nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/*.*" failed: No such file or 
 directory (2)" in manner "<command> || true" or something else. After that, all should be worked.

Comment: And (I forget ask it early), show permissions to script file.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk I updated the question with those details.

Comment: Try workaround in script('true' if command ended with error): '/usr/bin/rsync --chmod=u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx --remove-source-files -r -zvh --
 log-file=/var/log/rsync_activity.log /nfs/client_fs/NFSPRODW/*.* /NFSPRODW || true'. After that, try to run service and put output. Thanks.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: I will try all this scenario by itself when I came home and give feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, local version.

I’ve omitted ‘--remove-source-files’ in script for testing:

```
[root@centos7 rsync_task]# pwd
/root/rsync_task
[root@centos7 rsync_task]# ls -la backup.sh
-rw-r--r-x 1 root root 259 Feb 13 01:15 backup.sh
[root@centos7 rsync_task]# cat backup.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "List files in src: "$(ls /mnt/backup_src)
/usr/bin/rsync --chmod=u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx -r -zvh --log-file=/var/log/rsync_activity.log /mnt/backup_src/* /mnt/backup_dst
echo `date` ' Rsync - File(s) moved to NFS Share' >> /var/log/rsync_backup.log
```

Service file:

```
[root@centos7 rsync_task]# ls -lah /etc/systemd/system/rsync_backup.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 160 Feb 13 00:52 /etc/systemd/system/rsync_backup.service
[root@centos7 rsync_task]# cat /etc/systemd/system/rsync_backup.service
[Unit]
Description= Starts the folder monitoring/logging script
Documentation= man:systemd.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/rsync_task/backup.sh
```

Little check before start service:

```
[root@centos7 mnt]# pwd
/mnt
[root@centos7 mnt]# ls -lad backup_*
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  6 Feb 13 01:15 backup_dst
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 71 Feb 13 01:12 backup_src
[root@centos7 mnt]# ls backup_src/
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
[root@centos7 mnt]# ls backup_dst
```

Starting service:

```
[root@centos7 yurij]# systemctl start rsync_backup.service
[root@centos7 yurij]# systemctl status rsync_backup.service
● rsync_backup.service - Starts the folder monitoring/logging script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rsync_backup.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.service

Feb 13 01:24:11 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2714]: List files in src: file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
Feb 13 01:24:11 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2714]: sending incremental file list
Feb 13 01:24:11 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2714]: file1
Feb 13 01:24:11 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2714]: file2
Feb 13 01:24:11 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2714]: file3
Feb 13 01:24:11 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2714]: file4
Feb 13 01:24:11 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2714]: file5
Feb 13 01:24:11 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2714]: sent 236 bytes  received 107 bytes  686.00 bytes/sec
Feb 13 01:24:11 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2714]: total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
Feb 13 01:24:11 centos7.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Starts the folder monitoring/logging script.
```

Let's check backups:

```
[root@centos7 mnt]# ls backup_dst
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
```

Copy to NFS share (‘debian9’ is used as NFS-server).

NFS-sever configuration:

```
root@debian9:~/backups# pwd
/root/backups
root@debian9:~/backups# ls -ld ./
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Feb 13 01:35 ./
root@debian9:~/backups# cat /etc/exports
/root/backups 192.168.56.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,insecure)
root@debian9:~/backups# systemctl status nfs-server
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-02-13 01:32:10 MSK; 6min ago
  Process: 1631 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1628 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1625 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd 0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1645 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1643 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1645 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 13 01:32:10 debian9 systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Feb 13 01:32:10 debian9 systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

State of first host on which we doing backups:

```
[root@centos7 mnt]# pwd
/mnt
[root@centos7 mnt]# ls backup_src
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
[root@centos7 mnt]# ls backup_dst
[root@centos7 mnt]# mount|grep nfs
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
[root@centos7 mnt]# mount -t nfs 192.168.56.4:/root/backups backup_dst/
[root@centos7 mnt]# ls backup_dst
[root@centos7 mnt]# mount|grep nfs
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
192.168.56.4:/root/backups on /mnt/backup_dst type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.56.5,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.56.4)
```

Let's start the service:

```
[root@centos7 yurij]# systemctl start rsync_backup.service
[root@centos7 yurij]# systemctl status rsync_backup.service
● rsync_backup.service - Starts the folder monitoring/logging script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rsync_backup.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.service

Feb 13 01:43:25 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2874]: List files in src: file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
Feb 13 01:43:25 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2874]: sending incremental file list
Feb 13 01:43:25 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2874]: file1
Feb 13 01:43:25 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2874]: file2
Feb 13 01:43:25 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2874]: file3
Feb 13 01:43:25 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2874]: file4
Feb 13 01:43:25 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2874]: file5
Feb 13 01:43:26 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2874]: sent 236 bytes  received 107 bytes  228.67 bytes/sec
Feb 13 01:43:26 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[2874]: total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
Feb 13 01:43:26 centos7.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Starts the folder monitoring/logging script.

[root@centos7 mnt]# ls backup_dst
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
```

Checking on NFS-server:

```
root@debian9:~/backups# pwd
/root/backups
root@debian9:~/backups# ls
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
```

Finally, trying as ‘rsyncd’ which will be live in ‘debian9’ host:

```
root@debian9:~/backups# cat /etc/rsyncd.conf
log file=/var/log/rsyncd
[Backups]
    comment = backups
    path = /root/backups/
    use chroot = yes
    lock file = /var/lock/rsyncd
    read only = no
    write only = yes
    list = yes
    uid = root
    gid = root
    strict modes = yes
    hosts allow = 192.168.56.5 #it's my 'centos7'
    ignore errors = no
    ignore nonreadable = yes
    transfer logging = no
    timeout = 600
    refuse options = checksum dry-run
    dont compress = *.gz *.tgz *.zip *.z *.rpm *.deb *.iso *.bz2 *.tbz
root@debian9:~/backups# systemctl status rsync
● rsync.service - fast remote file copy program daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rsync.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-02-13 02:06:42 MSK; 33s ago
 Main PID: 2327 (rsync)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rsync.service
           └─2327 /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach

Feb 13 02:06:42 debian9 systemd[1]: Stopped fast remote file copy program daemon.
Feb 13 02:06:42 debian9 systemd[1]: Started fast remote file copy program daemon.
```

Check in backup directory on ‘debian9’:

```
root@debian9:~/backups# pwd
/root/backups
root@debian9:~/backups# ls
```

Make little changes in backup script:

```
[root@centos7 rsync_task]# cat backup.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "List files in src: "$(ls /mnt/backup_src)
/usr/bin/rsync --chmod=u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx -r -zvh --log-file=/var/log/rsync_activity.log /mnt/backup_src/* rsync://192.168.56.4/Backups
echo `date` ' Rsync - File(s) moved to NFS Share' >> /var/log/rsync_backup.log
```

Check in source files:

```
[root@centos7 mnt]# pwd
/mnt
[root@centos7 mnt]# ls backup_src/
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
```

Let's start service:

```
[root@centos7 yurij]# systemctl start rsync_backup.service
[root@centos7 yurij]# systemctl status rsync_backup.service
● rsync_backup.service - Starts the folder monitoring/logging script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rsync_backup.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.service

Feb 13 02:10:13 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[3021]: List files in src: file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
Feb 13 02:10:13 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[3021]: sending incremental file list
Feb 13 02:10:13 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[3021]: file1
Feb 13 02:10:13 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[3021]: file2
Feb 13 02:10:13 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[3021]: file3
Feb 13 02:10:13 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[3021]: file4
Feb 13 02:10:13 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[3021]: file5
Feb 13 02:10:13 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[3021]: sent 232 bytes  received 103 bytes  670.00 bytes/sec
Feb 13 02:10:13 centos7.localdomain backup.sh[3021]: total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
Feb 13 02:10:13 centos7.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Starts the folder monitoring/logging script.
```

Check in files on backup (rsynd) server:

```
root@debian9:~/backups# pwd
/root/backups
root@debian9:~/backups# ls
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
```

Comment: The service is starting fine now. I think I simply forgot to start service. I'm not sure what your doing beginning from 'Lets check backups:'.

Comment: I saw that backups are exists. In the very first comment I wrote about start service. Futher, I thought that you have done this. So, if problem have been solved, don't forget to mark this task as solved. I'm glad to see positive result in your task. P.S. Sorry for my English. I'm not native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'd check the SELinux context on your script file
/usr/etc/UHS_FolderMonitor.ksh  .  I had a similar problem with a systemd unit file using rsync.

Also see man 8 rsync_selinux (selinux-policy-doc package) for useful booleans.